# Программа выдает SyntaxError, но я не могу найти ошибку

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вот код:

```
file_read = open('D:\\test5.txt')
file_read1 = file_read.readlines()
file_read.close()

read_list = []
read_str = ""

read_str += str(file_read1)

for i in read_str:
    if i not in ("[,'()] "):
        read_list.append(i)

try:
    index = int(input("Enter the position of number, you want to know: ")

except IndexError:
    print("There are no numbers with such index")



for j in range(0, 5):

  num_1 = int(input("Input the first number: ")
  num_2 = int(input("Input the second number: ")

  try:
      division = num_1/num_2
      print(division)

  except ZeroDivisionError:
      print("You can't divide by zero")
```

Comment: У вас скобки пропущены.

Comment: Во-первых, когда вы получаете ошибку, в трейсбеке указан номер строки, в которой произошло исключение. Во-вторых, обратите внимание на симметричность скобок.

Comment: @mkkik спасибо. К сожалению номер строки с ошибкой почему-то не был указан.

Comment: Вопрос стоит удалить.